# enforce c source documentation in svn precommit hook using doxygen

Tags: c, svn, doxygen

As the title suggests, I want to enforce source code documentation for a C project managed in Subversion.

My idea is: set up a pre-commit hook that use doxygen for checking files with this options

```
   WARNINGS              = YES
   WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED  = YES
   WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR     = YES
   WARN_NO_PARAMDOC      = YES
```

The problem is: in order to have doxygen take into account a source file and raise warnings for undocumented members, It seems I must put into that file the "\file" documentation block as you see below.

```
/** \file foo.h
 * A file for testing how to enforce documentation
 *
 * if I don't put voluntarily this first "file" block, 
 * doxygen "ignores" the file and does not generate the warnings
 * I would expect (note that otherfunction is not documented)
 */


#ifndef FOO_H_
#define FOO_H_


/**
* \brief my test function 
* \param msg a simple string
* \return 0 if ok, 1 if not ok
*/
int testFunction(const char *msg);



int otherFunction(const char *msg);

#endif
```

If I don't doxygen "ignores" the file and no warning is raised.
This makes the check uneffective: users can easily forget to put the required block at the beginning of the source and commit without control.

Is there a way to make doxygen enforce the /file block in the beginning of the file?

Comment: Most IDEs support file templates in which you can add the `\file` tag. So if a file is created in the IDE the `\file` tag is automatically added.

Comment: Alternately... is the problem fixed if you change to document all (`EXTRACT_ALL = YES`)?  Is this why it is ignoring the files?